# In "SemVer.org" what does mean "It MAY include patch level changes" in item 7?

Tags: version, versioning, semantic-versioning

In http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html we have a "formal description" about how to manage software versioning in a way to create a standard and avoid some dependencies management problems. In the [item-spec-7](http://semver.org/#spec-item-7) we have as follows:

> Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated. It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. **It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.**

- **1)** What does the bold sentences exactly mean?

  - **1.1)** Means that I could choose any value for the *patch* that I want? But I could not just change the patch level from the current value?

Item **1.1** makes senses for me, but the sentences order confused me. After all, the Minor value had just been incremented and the *patch* was reset to 0(zero).

Did I get it right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand in the iten-spec 7 of [sermver.org (2.0.0)](https://semver.org/), that descibes how to increment Minor version value:

> 7. Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated. It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. It **MAY include** patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

It **MAY include** patch level changes into the code in this new version with Minor incremented. But only patch level changes could not lead us to a Minor increment. In the other hand, it is expressed in item-spec 6:

> 6. Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if **only backwards compatible bug fixes are introduced**. A bug fix is defined as an internal change that fixes incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

Means that if you are on **1.1.0**, then you want to release a bunch of patch level changes, you may bump to **1.2.0**
If you were at **1.1.23** and want to release a next minor, then you must reset the patch, **1.2.0**

Comment: About your answer: When you say "[...]release a bunch of patch level changes"[...] you are considering that only these changes would lead us to the minor value increment? Or that we had some other changes (anyone of the MUST ones) and we "included" the patch changes, so we would increment the Minor? What I am thinking now: Another hypothesis to me is that actually, we could go from 1.1.30 to 1.2.3, because: Minor had been incremented, Patch reset to zero and then, we included some patch level changes. What do you think?

Comment: Ohhh! The patch level changes are not about the patch value on the version, but yes patches changes into the code itself. Isn't it?. It **may include patch level changes**, not only **patch level changes** ... So I don't think that your answer is correct. Because, reading what your said seems like if we have just patch level changes we could increment Minor, wich is wrong. Item-spec 6 describes how to deal with only patch level changes, as far I understand. Thank you for your help anyway, I really appreciated.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. What it means is, you can also include patch level changes with your minor level changes by bumping the minor and resetting patch to zero.